# Problems Populating the Google Tag Manager datalayer

Tags: javascript, html, opencart, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

For the past few days I have been trying to populate the Google Tag Manager datalayer on the OpenCart product page when the button "Add to Cart" is clicked.

I understand that I need to use the push method, but I can't figure out where to nest it since I have no HTML button just a JavaScript function.

The function:

```js
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
  type: 'post',
  data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function() {
   $('#button-cart').button('loading');
  },
  complete: function() {
   $('#button-cart').button('reset');
  },
  success: function(json) {
   $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
   $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

   if (json['error']) {
    if (json['error']['option']) {
     for (i in json['error']['option']) {
      var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));

      if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
       element.parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
      } else {
       element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
      }
     }
    }

    if (json['error']['recurring']) {
     $('select[name=\'recurring_id\']').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</div>');
    }

    // Highlight any found errors
    $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
   }

   if (json['success']) {
    $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

    $('#cart > button').html('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total']);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
   }
  },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
 });
});
```

I turned the internet up side down but found no solution to this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: update your question with the code you have so far

Comment: @ztadic91 I would gladly but I have none since I don't know where the code should be placed. I could post a screenshot of where I think it should go?

Comment: did you read the [manual](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide) ?

Comment: yes, but I have not button where I can nest the push method, it seems to be a javascript function

Comment: i update the question with the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code from your question you have already initialized the click handler for the "Add to cart" button. Put your dataLayer logic inside the click handler.

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'button-add-to-cart-click'
    });
    // other code
});
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I have one follow up question, how do I go about pushing the name of the product that is being viewed? I tried adding `'product_title': '$heading_title'` but this seems to brake the code.

Comment: remove the `'` from the `$heading_title`, without them you are pushing a variable's value, if inside the `'` then it's just a string. ex. `'product_title': $heading_title,`

Comment: Just putting the variable in won't work, but defining a new variable and assigning the value to ti like this `var naslov = <?php echo json_encode($heading_title); ?>;` works, then it's just a matter of calling it below. Hvala puno na pomoći :)